# Create a rolling sum & average of different variables in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with lots of environmental data which looks something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'temperature' : np.random.uniform(5,15, 500), 'Precipitation' : np.random.uniform(0, 3, 500)}, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=500, freq='H'))
df['TempUnit'] = 'celsius'
df['PrecipUnit'] = 'mm'
```

[image]

I want to create new columns from this data which calculates 6 hourly average of temperature, and 6 hourly sums of precipitation. I am using the following method:

```
df['rolling_sum_by_time'] = df.groupby(df.index.time)['Precipitation'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling('6h').sum())
```

This is not summing the data - it gives the output below, I am not sure where I am going wrong here.
[image]

I have also tried creating a new dataframe using `groupby` like so:

```
temp_6h = df.groupby('temperature').rolling('6H').mean()
```

which screws up the dates and puts them out of order (not what I want):

[image]

Ideally what I am looking for is a dataframe which looks like this (below), where every six hours the values in the previous 6 hours are summed (for precipitation) and averaged (for temperature). Ideally I would like this to work at specified 6 hour intervals, i.e. at 0600, 1200, 1800, and 2400 hours.

[image]

I'd greatly appreciate some help! Thank you.

Comment: You groupby on `time` but rolling for `6H`, that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html You want to resample with 6H.

Comment: @QuangHoang I get the same result when using groupby.index - I will look into it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way.

```
df['temp_avg'] = df.temperature.resample('6h',label = 'right', closed = 'right').mean()
df['precip_sum'] = df.Precipitation.resample('6h', label ='right', closed='right').sum()
```

Comment: I get the error: MergeError: Must pass right_on or right_index=True

Comment: Thanks - this gives a dataframe with 84 rows for temperature data with 6 hourly intervals, but it removes my original data (the 500 rows).

I think by doing this `df['temp_avg'] = df.temperature.resample('6h').mean()` I can create it in a new column, keeping the previous data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217820/discussion-between-manishankar-singh-and-pad).

Comment: This works but there is one issue - the values at each 6 hour timestamp are incorrect - the value at 2020-01-01 06:00:00 should be a sum/avg of the previous 6 values (from 01:00:00 to 06:00:00. Using your method it is actually an average of the values from 06:00:00 to 11:00:00. The value at each 6 hour period should be an average/sum of the previous 6 values, not the following ones.

Comment: Manishankar - yes - this fixes all the issues - thank you! To clean it up ever so slightly `df['temp_avg'] = df.temperature.resample('6h',label = 'right', closed = 'right').mean()` and `df['precip_sum'] = df.Precipitation.resample('6h', label ='right', closed='right').sum()` does it in a few less characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mport pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'temperature' : np.random.uniform(5,15, 500), 'Precipitation' : np.random.uniform(0, 3, 500)}, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=500, freq='H'))
df['TempUnit'] = 'celsius'
df['PrecipUnit'] = 'mm'

rolling_sum_by_time = []
for x in range(0,len(df["Precipitation"])):
    P = [df["Precipitation"][x-2+i] for i in range(6) if x-2+i >= 0 and x-2+i < len(df["Precipitation"])]
    rolling_sum_by_time.append(sum(P))
df['rolling_sum_by_time'] = rolling_sum_by_time

rolling_sum_by_time = []
for x in range(0,len(df["Precipitation"])):
    P = [df["Precipitation"][x-2+i] for i in range(6) if x-2+i >= 0 and x-2+i < len(df["Precipitation"])]
    rolling_sum_by_time.append(sum(P)/len(P))
df['rolling_sum_by_time'] = rolling_sum_by_time

temp_6h = []
for x in range(0,len(df["temperature"])):
    P = [df["temperature"][x-2+i] for i in range(6) if x-2+i >= 0 and x-2+i < len(df["temperature"])]
    temp_6h.append(sum(P))
df['temp_6h'] = temp_6h
```

Comment: Did this work for you? This did not sum the precip values for me - sorry.

Comment: Thanks - but this gives me a column for rolling sum that has lower values for precipitation, it doesn't seem to be summing them at all, and it sums the temp data too.

Comment: Yes, in the corners, it will only sum 3 or 4.